# How to use a trained keras model to do classification in an android application

Tags: android, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I am building an android application that takes some real time image from the camera of the mobile and classifies them into different classes. For this I first built a deep-learning model in keras and have already trained it using sufficient data and saved the weights in a .hdf5 file. Now, how I can use this model to do real time predictions of the image, taken using android camera in android application.

Basically, is there any way that I can use the weights in .hdf5 file to do the predictions in real time in android application?
Or, is there any other way to train the model such that the model can be deployed in android to do image classification in android application.

Comment: Very interesting question I'm sure I'll have some day....
Maybe you could try asking for how to port a model to java or other major language with more users. Probably the answer will come faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to keras. But even I am trying to build a similar application by training the model in keras and developing an android app.
I came across Siraj Raval's youtube video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFWKdLOxykE&t=673s

You need to save the weights in .pb files and export the model to android.

Please check if it is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Complete tutorial - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/index.html#7